# test data time series - how can I merge 2 data sets?

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets: one with test results (nedl_1) and another with more test results (subset_cal1) and a time for these tests(dc_time). I'd like to merge the data by ID shown in File column (for ex. 180061). I first transposed subset_cal1 and now column name in both datasets are about the same (except "."). Then I'll try to join them. However, joining them is not possible as one data set is numeric and the other is factor (due to transpose).

I coerced the transposed subset_cal_1 into numeric but dc_time column got coerced into a number. I think I'm forcing something here and I'd rather learn how to do it right because it will come up again.

nedl_1

```
  Wavelength      18005.1      18006.1      18009.1      18010.1      18012.1
1        350 7.920042e-10 8.118013e-10 1.002651e-09 7.379407e-10 9.285596e-10
2        351 7.990535e-10 6.535653e-10 1.275650e-09 5.742704e-10 9.042697e-10
```

subset_cal1

```
   File                  dc_time Channels  it calibration instrument_num
1 180061 Fri Jan 20 15:37:40 2012     2151 136           1          18006
2 180091 Fri Jan 27 13:30:23 2012     2151 136           1          18009
3 180101 Fri Jan 27 09:41:38 2012     2151 136           1          18010
4 180121 Tue Feb 28 12:15:02 2012     2151 136           1          18012
```

Here is the code that I used to transpose subset_cal1 and then join with nedl_1

```
n <- subset_cal1$File                          # remember the characters in $File 
sh_raw <- as.data.frame(t(subset_cal1[,-1]))   # transpose all but $File
colnames(sh_raw) <- n                          #  change colnames to those stored in n

dups <- unique(as.list(sh_raw))        # list the duplicate cols
sh_raw_2 <- sh_raw[!duplicated(dups)]  # remove duplicate cols

j_raw_nedl <- left_join(sh_raw, nedl_1)   #join matching cols
```

Error: Can't join on '18051.1' x '18051.1' because of incompatible types (numeric / character)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share reproducible data with `dput` with expected output

Comment: Thank you Dave2e for reformatting:)

Comment: Also, please show not tell us your code.